# IIS Redirect from HTTPS to HTTP

Tags: redirect, https, iis-8

In my site we don't have SSL installed. When user try the site https://example.com it shows the user the site is unsecure etc. Instead I want to redirect them to the http version of the site. I tried redirect in the IIS but still user see this message.

Is there any way to prevent the unsecure message to the users and also redirect to http site?

Thanks

Comment: No, there is no way to do that. The SSL handshake is the first thing that occurs, you can't send anything before that. You could only disable https completely.

Comment: You need a valid SSL certificate to accept any requests via HTTPS. Even for redirects.